# MkMapView not plotting annotation view at (0,0)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am facing a problem with loading the custom annotation view on the mapkit with latitude and longitude as 0. If I shift the lat long just a little, the code runs fine. I am unable to get the issue. I am using Apple Map and the annotation view is custom.

Comment: You write "I am facing a problem."  You also write "I am unable to get the issue."  So which is true?  What does "If I shift the lat long just a little" mean?

Comment: If I shift the lat long just a little means that I give latitude and longitude as 0.00001, then the view get loaded but not at 0.